# array of strings into a DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm reading each line of a file into an array of strings:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
```

Each line is separated by a tab

```
lines[0] = "John\tPizza\tRed\tApple"
```

I want to load this string array into a DataGridView.  I tried the following:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Name",typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Food",typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Color",typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Fruit",typeof(string));

foreach(string s in lines)
{
   dt.Rows.Add(s);
}

myDataGridView.DataSource = dt;
```

The problem is that all the strings are loaded to the first column of the DataGrid:

[image]

I need them to be separated like this:

[image]

Comment: You need to split each line by that delimiter, and then add each of those split values to each column for each row, instead of `dt.Rows.Add(s);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to split the lines on the tab. Here is an example:

```
foreach (string s in lines)
{
   var splitLine = s.Split("\t");
   dt.Rows.Add(splitLine);
}
```

I also found some [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/adding-data-to-a-datatable) that says you need to create a new row with the NewRow() method and then fill out each column value. Here is what that would look like:

```
foreach (string s in lines)
{
   // Split the line
   var splitLine = s.Split("\t");

   // Create the new row
   var newRow = dt.NewRow();
   newRow["Name"] = splitLine[0];
   newRow["Food"] = splitLine[1];
   newRow["Color"] = splitLine[2];
   newRow["Fruit"] = splitLine[3];

   // Add the row to the table
   dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
}
```